# Declare same route twice but expect different behaviour according to a middleware

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I started creating a REST API using the lumen framework and wanted to set up a particular behaviour for my `GET /user` route. Behaviour is the following:

- If the request come from an authenticated user (using `auth` middleware), the method `getAllFields` from `UserController` is called and return all the data from the `user`
- If it's not the case, the method `get` from `UserController` is called and return some of the data from the `user`

It seems logic to me to just write it like that in my `web.php` using a simple middleware:

```php
<?php

$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/user/{id}',  [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getAllFields'
    ]);
});

$router->get('/user/{id}',  [
    'uses' => 'UserController@get'
]);
```

But for some reason, even if the middleware is correct, I always get the response of the second route declaration (that call `get()`). I precise that if I remove the second route declaration, the one in the middleware work as expected.

Have someone an idea how I can achieve something similar that work?

Comment: What do you want to return if user is not logged in?

Comment: Example is maybe not really good but an authenticated `user` will be able to get is `email` and personal data. If he is not connected, he will only get the 'public' data of this user like `name`, `firstname`, ...

Comment: Why is name, first name public? Are you designing a leaderboard for a contest?

Comment: It's just for the example I don't have any `firstname` in my DB. It was just supposed to represent the 'public' data

Comment: Don't show anything in public data. It doesn't make sense. Redirect them to login page.

Comment: If you go to my Stackoverflow account in Incognito mode you will see some public data

Comment: Those are other user profiles. If you are asking about that, then regardless of whether the user is logged in or not, you should show same amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Router will check if your request matches to any declared route. Middleware will run AFTER that match, so You cannot just return to router and try to find another match.

To fallow Laravel and Routes pattern - You should have single route that will point to method inside controller. Then inside that You can check if user is logged or not and execute getAllFields() from that controller. It will be not much to rewrite since You are currently using UserController in both routes anyway.

**web.php**

```
$router->get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@get');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function get()
{
   return auth()->check() ? YourMethodForLogged() : YourMethodForNotLogged();
}
```

Or if there is not much logic You can keep this in single method.

Also it is good idea to fallow Laravels REST standards (so use show instead of get, "users" instead of "user" etc - read more https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers)

**web.php**

```
$router->get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function show(User $user)
{
   if (auth()->check()) {
      //
   } else {
      //
   }
}
```

To summary - for your needs use Auth inside controller instead of middleware.
To check if user is logged You can use Facade Auth::check() or helper auth()->check(), or opposite Auth::guest() or auth()->guest().

If you are actually using Lumen instead of full Laravel then there is not auth helper by default (You can make own or use package like lumen-helpers) or just keep it simple and use just Facades instead (if You have then enabled in Lumen).

Read more https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication and https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Comment: Yeah it's exactly what I want have you the name of the concept that enable the use of `auth`? Should I import it?

Comment: @johannchopin check update. Facades and helpers are global, so you do not need to import anything to check if user is logged or not.

Comment: It's working perfectly thanks for your help and the tips about REST convention. Maybe you can precise that in Lumen it's not `auth()->check()` but `Auth::check()`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is against the idea of Laravel's routing. Each route should be defined once.

You can define your route without `auth` middleware enabled and then define your logic in the controller.

Comment: Yes but in this case I have to reemplement the middleware logic inside of the controller. Is there to avoid rewrite it and respect the DRY concept?

Comment: Keep in mind that the purpose of any middleware is some *side effect*, so the middleware itself doesn't serve as the source of truth. You can happily use the condition used in `auth` middleware in your code, just take a look at its code.